# static class template member: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates

Here is a minimum working example of a pooled object I'm trying to create (obviously not feature complete - I'm just trying to illustrate the problem I'm having)

I have a class template `Storage` which contains `aligned_storage`:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Storage
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> data[N];
};
```

I then have a base class template `PoolObj` which allocates out of a static class member of template parameter `T` using `operator new`:

```
template<typename T>
struct PoolObj
{
    static void* operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "new T\n";
        return &T::pool.data[0];
    }

    static void operator delete(void* p, std::size_t size)
    {
        std::cout << "delete T\n";
    }
};
```

Now I have a class which inherits from `PoolObj`, and has a static `Storage` member `pool`, so that when I create an instance using `new`, I will get storage from the pool.

```
struct Foo : PoolObj<Foo>
{
    static Storage<Foo, 10> pool;
};

Storage<Foo, 10> Foo::pool {};
```

This all works fine:

```
int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo();
    delete f;
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> $ ./a.out
> new T
> delete T
> ```

Now, however, I am now trying to make a `PoolObj` enabled **class template**:

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar : PoolObj<Bar<T>>
{
    static Storage<Bar<T>, 10> pool;
};

template<typename T>
Storage<Bar<T>, 10> Bar<T>::pool {};
```

This does not work

```
int main()
{
    Bar<int>* b = new Bar<int>();
    delete b;
    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile I get the following errors:

> ```
> In instantiation of ‘struct Storage<Bar<int>, 10ul>’:
>    required from ‘struct Bar<int>’
>  error: invalid application of ‘sizeof’ to incomplete type ‘Bar<int>’
>   std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> data[N];
> ```

- Why is `T` in `Storage` complete for `Foo`, but incomplete for `Bar<int>` et al?
- Is it possible to achieve the design I am hoping for here?

**Full example below:** [(and on coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/91b626919818f3c2)

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T, std::size_t N>
struct Storage
{
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> data[N];
};

template<typename T>
struct PoolObj
{
    static void* operator new(std::size_t size)
    {
        return &T::pool.data[0];
    }

    static void operator delete(void* p, std::size_t size)
    {
    }
};

struct Foo : PoolObj<Foo>
{
    static Storage<Foo, 10> pool;
};

Storage<Foo, 10> Foo::pool {};

template<typename T>
struct Bar : PoolObj<Bar<T>>
{
    static Storage<Bar<T>, 10> pool;
};

template<typename T>
Storage<Bar<T>, 10> Bar<T>::pool {};

int main()
{
    Foo* f = new Foo();
    delete f;

    Bar<int>* b = new Bar<int>();
    delete b;

    return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

Interestingly [this works fine in clang (coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26bd19741ceb8638).

- Which compiler is correct?
- Is this a bug in gcc?

**2nd Edit:**

According to the comments, it works find in VS2017 too. As such, I guess I'm leaning towards a bug in gcc?

Comment: I guess this is because you are using Bar<T> as part of the definition of the class Bar<T>. Not sure enough to make it an official answer. But the error does make sense.

Comment: Just to add on it, if the compiler tries to understand the size of the static member pool during the definition of `Bar<T>`, then at this point `Bar<T>` is incomplete.  When it will check for `std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)>` to understand the size of pool, `Bar<T>` (T in this context) is still incomplete, and taking sizeof incomplete type is illegal.

Comment: @OriBS `Storage` is only instantiated for `Bar<T>` when we declare `Bar<int>`. At the point at which it is instantiated it has complete type surely? Additionally, it works under clang - which compiler is correct?

Comment: @OriBS: I won't see here why type would be incomplete only for template case.

Comment: The thing is that pool is a static member of  Bar<T>, and therefore doesn't contribute to the size of Bar<T>, so in principle the compiler can know the size of Bar<T>, so I tend to agree with clang. But i'm not sure what the standard has to say about it

Comment: btw, your example compiles with visual studio 2017 as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which compiler is correct?

generally speaking, the relevant wording should be

> **[temp.inst-2]** The implicit instantiation of a class template specialization causes the implicit instantiation of the declarations, **but not of the definitions**, default arguments, or noexcept-specifiers of the class member functions, member classes, scoped member enumerations, static data members, member templates, and friends

and

> **[temp.inst-3]** Unless a member of a class template or a member template has been explicitly instantiated or explicitly specialized, the specialization of the member is implicitly instantiated when the specialization is referenced in a context that requires the member definition to exist or if the existence of the definition of the member affects the semantics of the program; in particular, **the initialization (and any associated side effects) of a static data member does not occur unless the static data member is itself used in a way that requires the definition of the static data member to exist**.

the static member variable is a declaration but not a definition, so clang is right.

That said, both compilers behave wildly when deciding what "*to instantiate a declaration but not a definition*" and "*a context that requires the member definition to exist or if the existence of the definition of the member affects the semantics of the program*" mean (you can find a lot of corner cases here on SO, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47196863/initializer-sizeoft-of-inline-static-auto-does-it-need-instantiation/47230580#comment81426924_47230580) recently).

---

As a workaround, you may use a static reference instead

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar : PoolObj<Bar<T>>
{
    static Storage<Bar<T>, 10>&& pool;
};

template<typename T>
Storage<Bar<T>, 10>&& Bar<T>::pool = Storage<Bar<T>, 10>{}; // note, the temporary is lifetime-extended here
```

this seems to persuade both clang and gcc to avoid instantiating the aligned_storage (as it should be).