# Hinnant's stack allocator with boost rtrees: compilation failure

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, memory-management, allocator

I am trying to use Howard Hinnant's [`stack_alloc`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.h) with boost rtrees, as in the following example:

```cpp
#include "stack_alloc.h"
#include <boost/geometry/index/rtree.hpp>

using NodePoint = boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian>;
using Linear = boost::geometry::index::linear<8, 2>;
using RTree =
    boost::geometry::index::rtree<NodePoint, Linear, boost::geometry::index::indexable<NodePoint>,
                                  boost::geometry::index::equal_to<NodePoint>,
                                  stack_alloc<NodePoint, 100>>;

int main()
{
    RTree my_tree{};

    return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile with a fairly sizeable template error stack. I think the heart of the issue is:

> /usr/local/include/boost/geometry/index/detail/rtree/node/variant_static.hpp:26:7: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::allocators, 100>, boost::geometry::model::point, boost::geometry::index::linear<8, 2>, boost::geometry::model::box >, boost::geometry::index::detail::rtree::node_variant_static_tag>'

Here is the full example on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/915f45841475390e) with the full error.

What is wrong here?

I tried using `stack_alloc` with various boost collections, like `boost::container::static_vector` and `boost::container::map` and those worked fine.
I also tried using another `stack_allocator` implementation from [this SO reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28574062/713659) and got the same error.

Furthermore, I am aware that there is an updated implementation from Howard Hinnant, namely [`short_alloc`](https://howardhinnant.github.io/short_alloc.h). I tried using it, but this implementation has no default ctor and requires us to provide the storage at construction time. Since `boost` takes the allocator as a template parameter and instantiates it internally, I could not find a way to make this work, but will happily use it if there is a way. Further info for `stack_alloc` and/vs `short_alloc`: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722907/hinnants-short-alloc-and-alignment-guarantees), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722907/hinnants-short-alloc-and-alignment-guarantees/34211227#34211227), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11652436)

Comment: Boost tree has a constructor that takes a user-provided allocator object: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/spatial_indexes/boost__geometry__index__rtree/rtree_parameters_type_const____indexable_getter_const____value_equal_const____allocator_type_const___.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The heart of the issue is essentially a circular dependency.

Constructing the `RTree` causes the `rtree<...>` template instantiation which includes a typedef `node_pointer = allocators_type::node_pointer`, which triggers the instantiation of `allocators_type`, i.e. `detail::rtree::allocators<...>`, which has a base class of `detail::rtree::node_alloc<...>`, which in its definition rebinds the allocator to the node type. The node type is a variant of `detail::rtree::variant_leaf<...>` and `detail::rtree::variant_internal_node<...>`.

But `stack_alloc` needs the `sizeof(T)`, so both templates included in the `variant` types get instantiated, and when instantiating `variant_internal_node`, it needs `Allocators::node_pointer`, so `Allocators` must be instantiated, but isn't that what we're in the middle of instantiating!

I suggest trying `short_alloc` and passing the allocator to the container. Because it separates the storage from the allocator type, it should not require completeness of the template type, breaking the circle.

Comment: Yeah, the circular dependency was/is the issue. I attempted to workaround it with tricks like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462707/static-class-template-member-invalid-application-of-sizeof-to-incomplete-type) and forward declarations to no avail. Using `short_alloc` and the constructor I had previously missed lead to a working solution! This is probably better anyway since `short_alloc` is conformant, whereas `stack_alloc` is not ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11648202/questions-about-hinnants-stack-allocator/11652436#11652436)). Thanks!