# unexpected invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type error

Tags: c++, templates, g++, language-lawyer

In the following code

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T >
struct Allocator {
    using element_type = std::aligned_storage_t< sizeof( T ) >;
};

template< typename T >
struct MPT {
    static Allocator< MPT > allocator;
};

using RV = MPT< double >;

template<>
Allocator< RV > RV::allocator = {};
```

g++ yields the following error: invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'MPT'.

I tried using g++ 10.2 using Compiler Explorer (https://godbolt.org/z/ran4or). Clang and MSVC do not complain (see https://godbolt.org/z/nsE5Yj and https://godbolt.org/z/7c7n4e).

Is this really an example of an incomplete type? Which compiler is correct here?

Comment: I'd posit this example https://godbolt.org/z/cjG4sq to postulate this is a GCC bug. Explicitly instantiating `Allocator<RV>` magically makes the static member definition well-formed. I don't see how `RV` is more complete in this case.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica: But isn't `MTP` not yet defined within the definition of `MTP`? How can the compiler know the size of `MTP` at that time?

Comment: @florestan - It doesn't have to know it. A compiler is not supposed to instantiate a type fully unless required by the context it's used in. And static members may be declared with an incomplete type at the point of declaration https://wandbox.org/permlink/rdsQmdV8eEDcO1HC . So there is no need to instantiate  `Allocator< MPT >` along with the `MPT` specialization. It may be deferred.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Ok, I need a language lawyer then (*checking my phone book*). At least I seem to have a workaround thanks to your example.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462707/static-class-template-member-invalid-application-of-sizeof-to-incomplete-type?

Comment: Prolly related gcc bug https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84075

Comment: Hah, I just thought of calling a @LanguageLawyer, and _SWISSHH_ one pops up. Great! Most probable this is GCC Bug 84075, but my example seems to be the simplest given in the context. Should I append a comment or file a new bug and let the experts decide? Hmm...

Comment: side question, why is MPT being passed down and not T, T is unused, what is the point of this code

Comment: @Giel There is no point. This is the minimal code I could come up with to reproduce the error. The point of the original program struchture is completely gone, admittetly.